# Why my webservice method is not updating its parameters in the wsdl?

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl

I modified my webservices and added one new parameter. I re-compile everything and when I ran in my localhost everything works fine. BUT when I deployed into my IIS server the wsdl is not being updated and it simply do not show my new parameter.

What do I have to do for my wsdl to be updated?

Comment: The environment is out of date, did you redeploy the updated service reference files?

Comment: what do you mean when you say "Reference Files"?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the web reference and click update. It will update the reference.cs file. Then compile and deploy. Make sure it reference the new reference.cs file.

Comment: What do you mean by "Web Reference"? in my solution explorer I don't have anything called web reference. The only thing I have is the asmx file!.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the question. I thought you are consuming your web service through another application. Anyway, did you deploy the updated wsdl file to IIS??

Comment: I do not have a WSDL file either.
I just have a directory with all .asmx and bin folder with the .dll and two xml files. I just copy/pasted EVERYTHING.

Comment: Grrr... My bad again. Not wsdl ... I mean asmx file in the previous comment. :-o

Comment: Also try restarting the app pool for the IIS.

Comment: Every asmx file must have a corresponding .cs file too ... Look in the App_Code folder and make sure that they have your new parameter.

Answer (score 0):

When you say the wsdl is not being updated to show the new parameter how are you trying to access the wsdl? if you are trying to access `http://myserver/myservice/service.asmx?wsdl` and the updated wsdl is not showing up, try restarting the web application/website on IIS that hosts the `service.asmx`. If that doesn't solve it try redeploying the code. If on the other hand you are stating that a client application that is consuming the service you have hosted on IIS cannot see the updated wsdl you need to check the code of the client application not your service. If it has a web reference pointing to the URL where your service is hosted then you need to do what Azhar suggested and right click on the web reference and click update. If it has a proxy class generated by wsdl.exe then regenerate the proxy class by using wsdl.exe as follows

`wsdl /namespace:MyCompany.MyApp.Services /out:C:\MyServiceProxy.cs http://myserver/myservice/service.asmx`

and update the client project with the new MyServiceProxy.cs file which should contain the method with the updated parameters.